# How could javascript figure out the (i)frame hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-chrome-extension, hierarchy

How could chrome extension javascript figure out the whole page (i)frame hierarchy?

Please remember users can click links and the sub frames could be in any location.

In the end the extension needs to know:

- root: B.com/blah.html

  - sub-frame: c.com/foo.jsp

    - sub-frame: d.com/bar.asp
    - sub-frame: e.com/index.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to somthing like this ,
 just change the ** elementID ** :

```
 var parents = $("#elementID").parents("*");

  for (i = parents.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

   //your code
 }
```

Comment: I don't think .parents(...) can go beyond its own frame. Can it?